# Compare thread IDs using windows api

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winapi

I'm working with windows api threads and I would like to compare thread IDs.

First I create a thread with [CreateThread()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and store the handle( HANDLE ) and ID ( LPDWORD ) that I get from the function.

Then I get the handle and id from the created thread using [GetCurrentThread()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683182%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetThreadId()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I always get different values for both handles and both IDs.

Is there a way to compare threads in a similar fashion as pthread?

*I'm doing this to as a debug option to confirm correct execution. I have always gotten correct results from other libraries( pthread.h, threads.h) but not from windows api. It is not a critical problem but I would like to learn the procedure in winapi*

Comment: Just curious, does GetCurrentThreadId() return the value you're expecting?

Comment: @HerrJoebob Yes it gets the correct value. If I use GetThreadId() from GetCurrentThread() in the thread I also get the correct value. But doing that in main gives the wrong value.

Comment: If those two variants work, I'm not sure what exactly is going wrong. In any case, "get the handle [...] from the created thread using GetCurrentThread()" sounds wrong, as the current thread is the one that is executing the call, so you are only getting the value for this thread, not a different one. Can you clarify and maybe add some code and elaborate on what exactly you expect? As it stands, your question can't be answered.

Comment: Only compare thread IDs, not handle values.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using  GetCurrentThread() and GetThreadId(), you can use GetCurrentThreadId() [[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx%5d).
As said before, don't use pseudo-HANDLE (returned by GetCurrentThread()) on another thread.

From what I know, there could several different HANDLE to one thread but ID should be an unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

`GetCurrentThread()` does not return a real handle. From MSDN:

> Retrieves a pseudo handle for the calling thread.
>   ...
>   A pseudo handle is a special constant that is interpreted as the current thread handle.

You cannot compare this value to the result of `CreateThread()`. If you are using this value in `GetThreadId()` from a different thread, you will also not get the ID you want.

You can use `DuplicateHandle()` on the pseudo handle to retrieve the real handle.

Comment: Updated my answer. You can e.g. use DuplicateHandle().

Comment: Do you have any info on the function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx this seems correct but compiler insists that my two arguments aren't enough.

Comment: That's the wrong function, I mean [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Using DuplicateHandle gives a different handle( not the same as in main ) but the same wrong result.

Comment: I have just figured it out, will post an answer when I get the time.

Comment: Are you still comparing handles? You can't do that, you need to use the handle to get the thread ID. You can have multiple different handles to the same thread. But a thread only has one ID.

Comment: I was always comparing IDs obviously( never HANDLE but I still gave information just in case). The problem was actually something different, inherent to HANDLE type.